# Phalcon Framework volt template engine

Tags: php, phalcon, volt

I want to render a simple page so I can benchmark the performance. I use phalcon's volt engine

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt\Compiler;

$c = new Compiler();

$c->setOptions(['compiledPath' => '/tmp/']);

$c->compile('hello.volt');

require $c->getCompiledTemplatePath();
```

is all my code how do I now give over a variable that can be rendered in hello.volt

Doing simple math like {{ 7 + 12 }} is all I could achieve so far :/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt\Compiler;

$c = new Compiler();

$c->setOptions(['compiledPath' => '/tmp/']);

$c->compile('hello.volt');

$variables = array(
    'message' => 'world'
);

require $c->getCompiledTemplatePath();
```

Template:

```
{{ 'hello ' ~ variables['message'] }}
```

Compiled template is for real just a mixed PHP and HTML code. So once you are including it, you should be able to use there all variables that have been declared before including compiled template. In your case, `$c` variable:

```
{{ dump(c) }}
```

Share us you benchmarks! Especially if you are comparing Phalcon 1.3.4 with Phalcon 2+. Difference should be visible.

Comment: I'll try that thank you! I was comparing Twig, Smarty, Blade, fenom and Volt but since I have never even touched Phalcon I had no idea what I was doing.

Comment: Just tested it, Phalcon is awesome. The perfomance is like 10x as fast as Smarty or similar alternatives. Caching is helping this for sure

Comment: Since Phalcon 2.0 Volt part of phalcon is compiled from Zephir. Having a binary code for factoring templates is alone enough to beat Smarty and other in speed performance. Happy to see people interested in Phalcon, cheers :)